# Is Dart's async really async?

Tags: asynchronous, dart

Given the following code

```
import 'dart:async';

var total = 0;
final iterations = 10000000;

Future add() async {
  print('starting add -> $total');

  for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    total += 1;
  }

  print('ending add -> $total');
}

Future sub() async {
  print('starting sub -> $total');

  for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    total -= 1;
  }

  print('ending sub -> $total');
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  add();
  sub();
  print('done');
}
```

which generates the following output

```
done
starting add -> 0
ending add -> 10000000
starting sub -> 10000000
ending sub -> 0
```

I wonder if `async` calls are really executed in an async fashion.

It looks like all `async` methods run in a second thread which is always the same, so **they are async for their callers, but not for each other**.

Am I right? If so, how can I execute multiple functions in an really async fashion (just like creating new threads)?

**edit**

I am not saying it has to be parallel. It can be async without being parallel. For example, an 1-core processor executes 1 instruction per cycle, but it does not mean that the processes are executed one by one. The processer intercales all processes and executes them **concurrently**, not in parallel. A VM with GIA also has this behavior.

This is not the behavior I am seeing here on Dart VM. When an async function is called, it is executed concurrently to its caller, but not to another async functions. I was expecting that an async function was concurrent to everything, not just to its caller.

I hope it is clear now.

Comment: "async to the caller" is pretty much the definition of async. It does not mean that they are executed in parallel (to the caller or anything else).

Comment: @Thilo, yes, I could not say "async" is a lie, but its behavior frustrates me. I was expecting something async to everything, not just to its caller.

Comment: Is this a version of Dart that compiles down to Javascript? If so, there is only a single thread in the execution engine.

Comment: @Thilo, no, it is running on Dart VM, I have no intention to compile it to JavaScript.

Comment: I think the Dart VM also uses a single-threaded event loop. For parallelism, you need to explicitly bundle code into "Isolates".

Comment: When executing code 'asynchronous' does not mean 'in parallel', it just means other code can run while waiting for the asynchronously executed code to complete.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus, please see my edit. The accepted answer explains why async functions are not concurrent nor parallel.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how async works. There is only one thread and an event queue where tasks are enqueued. When the previous sync execution is completed, then the next task in the queue is executed.

If you need parallel execution you can leverage isolates.

See also

- https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures
- https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop

**update**

Code in Dart (and when transpiled to JS) is executed single-threaded. Only one thread of execution is run at one time. 
When a task from the task queue is due to be executed, it is executed without interruption until it is completed. 
If this code calls async operations these async calls are added to the queue and executed when they are due.

In details it's a bit more complicated because there are also microtasks in addition to the event queue. Microtasks are processed before the next task from the task queue is processed, but this doesn't change that always one task is executed after the other without interruption.

This is the reason why it is important to not do long running calculations in the UI thread because this makes the UI non-responsive.