# Why Future is blocking the main thread?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app I'm using a FutureBuilder to run a Future but nevertheless it blocks the main UI thread. This is the code I'm using:

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: trace(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
     return ma;
    else
     return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
)
```

```
Future<void> trace() async {
  List<int> bytes = await widget.image.readAsBytes();
  img.Image imagee = img.decodeImage(bytes);
  var svg = potrace(imagee);
  ma = SvgPicture.string(svg);
}
```

EDIT:
With that code the CircularProgressIndicator is stuck while the image is processing, but when I change the function to this the progress indicator spins normally for 5 seconds.

```
Future<void> trace() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
img.Image imagee = await compute(img.decodeImage, bytes);
```

Comment: Need more inputs. What do you mean by "It blocks the main UI thread"? Does it freeze or keep showing CircularProgressIndicator? Did you try logging trace method?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me, that method *trace* doesn't return anything (because of type void), and *FutureBuilder* cannot build snapshot, because it's actually not getting anything?

Comment: @M.Obrcian The future doesn't return anything and he's not expecting any data out of future. He's using snapshot.connectionState to check the state of future.

Comment: @Amsakanna Isn't he expecting the *ma* from Future, in *return ma;* line?

Comment: @M.Obrcian No, the Future just updates the value of _ma_ and then FutureBuilder shows the updated _ma_ when it's done

Comment: @MrGian Ah, thanks.

Comment: @MrGian Did you log every line of trace method and find out where it is stuck? Also give the definition of potrace method.

Comment: @MrGian Also it is better to return `svg` from `trace()` method and construct the widget inside `FutureBuilder` like this `return SvgPicture.string(snapshot.data)`

Comment: Is `decodeImage` a sync function? If so, you should use the suggestion from Jim Chiu. If you want to know why there is another post explaination: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393674/is-darts-async-really-async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393674/is-darts-async-really-async).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use compute or isolate for background processing instead of processing in main thread

reference: [isolates](https://itnext.io/performance-programming-in-flutter-using-isolates-part-1-997a29011e88)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an network call http.get() request for a image file and perform an basic transition on a Container widget. You'll notice that it doesn't block the main thread.