# Why is the code before DART async modifies the method await synchronized?

Tags: dart, async-await

This is the code that uses Future

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  testFuture();
  print('main');
}

Future testFuture() {
  return Future(() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
    print('futureDone');
  });
}
```

The output is as follows

```
main
futureDone
```

When I want to use async to simplify my code, the code looks like this

```
Future testFuture() async{
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
  print('futureDone');
}
```

The output is as follows

```
futureDone
main
```

At first I was confused, I don't know why they output is different, I am looking for a lot of information, until I saw these words on the https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#execution-flow-with-async-and-await。

> An async function runs synchronously until the first await keyword. This means that within an async function body, all synchronous code before the first await keyword executes immediately.

I don't know why,So with that in mind, if I want to use async I need to write code like this.

```
Future testFuture() async{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0));
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {}
  print('futureDone');
}
```

The output is as follows

```
main
futureDone
```

By reading the [StackFlow problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393674/is-darts-async-really-async) in older versions of Dart, I found that the old version didn't
"An async function runs synchronously until the first await the keyword. This means that within An async function body, All synchronous code before the first await keyword Executes immediately. ", why did DART make such a change? Or is there something wrong with the way I use it?

Comment: There are always a cost when changing context. It makes sense you want to execute as much as possible instead of just putting an event on the event queue which we are going to execute immediately. E.g. the first code in the `async` method is most likely to be calling some code where we want to wait for the result. And maybe, there are a possibility that we don't always ends up `await` on something (e.g. if we implement some kind of cache).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change was made because the old behavior, of delaying the start of an async function, was getting in the way of people doing what they wanted to do.

Say you want to get the first ten elements of a stream. You'd write that as:

```dart
Future<List<T>> getTen<T>(Stream<T> stream) async {
  var list = <T>[];
  await for (var event in stream) {
    list.add(event);
    if (list.length == 10) break;
  }
  return list;
}
```

That looks perfectly fine. However, if the stream is a broadcast stream, and the `async` function delayed the first part of the code, then you wouldn't listen to the stream immediately, and might miss some events.

Another issue is things like reentrancy checking. If you want to prevent calling a function twice, you can do:

```dart
Result maybeDoFoo() {
  if (_mayDoFoo) return _doFoo();
  throw "Can't do foo!";
}
Result _doFoo() {
  mayDoFoo = false;
  var result = doTheActualFoo();
  mayDoFoo = true;
  return result;
}
```

Here the code guards you against calling `doFoo` while it's already executing.
Then you try to make the function async, perhaps because `doTheActualFoo` needs to depend on something which is already async, and you write:

```dart
Future<Result> maybeDoFoo() async {
  if (_mayDoFoo) return _doFoo();
  throw "Can't do foo!";
}
Future<Result> _doFoo() async {
  mayDoFoo = false;
  var result = doTheActualAsyncFoo();
  mayDoFoo = true;
  return result;
}
```

If the initial part of the async body is delayed, then there is an async gap between
the `if (mayDoFoo)` and the `mayDoFoo = false`, which means that you can call `doFoo` twice, both seeing `mayDoFoo` as true, and then *slightly later* both of them enter the `_doFoo` function. That breaks the security of this pattern completely.
Such code was found in the wild.

The behavior of `async` functions was changed to run immediately to avoid mistakes like this. It was too unpredictable in its original behavior, and code patterns which worked well in synchronous code would become subtly fragile when directly ported to being async. With that change, delays only happen at `await`s, not anywhere else, making it more predictable what's actually going on.
(Well, almost, because `async*` functions are still delayed from the call to `listen` on its stream, so they can lose broadcast stream events.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It took me some time to understand what you meant.

Comment: First, I learned that not only is the code before 'await' synchronized, but the code on the same line as 'await' is also synchronized. Then I understood your first Stream example.

Comment: And then I spent some time modifying your second example to get it running, and I saw how it prevents double calls.

Comment: This is indeed a necessary change, but I find it hard to understand for a novice like me.

Answer (score 0):

LRN answer code example

This is the old version of the code

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  maybeDoFoo().then((value) => print(value));
  maybeDoFoo().then((value) => print(value));
}
bool mayDoFoo = true;
Future maybeDoFoo() async{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0));
  if (mayDoFoo) return _doFoo();
  return("Can't do foo!");
}
Future _doFoo() async{
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0));
  mayDoFoo = false;
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  var result = 1;
  mayDoFoo = true;
  return result;
}
```

print:

> 1
>
> 1

now

```
void main(List<String> args) {

  maybeDoFoo().then((value) => print(value));
  maybeDoFoo().then((value) => print(value));
}
bool mayDoFoo = true;
Future maybeDoFoo() async{
  // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0));
  if (mayDoFoo) return _doFoo();
  return("Can't do foo!");
}
Future _doFoo() async{
  // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0));
  mayDoFoo = false;
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  var result = 1;
  mayDoFoo = true;
  return result;
}
```

print:

> Can't do foo!

> 1